# Android App Crashes When I Try to Show HelloWorld After Button Is Clicked

Tags: android

I have written a simple app that is supposed to show a button and when that button is clicked, it will show the text: 'Hello World' - however all it is doing is crashing at the moment.

The XML is:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hello"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text=""
        tools:context=".GraphicsActivity" />

    <Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:id="@+id/button_send"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Write Something..."
        android:onClick="writeMsg" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The Android source is here:

```
public class GraphicsActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_graphics);
    }

    public void WriteMsg() {

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_send);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello);
                tv.setText("Hello World");
                setContentView(tv);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

As I say, all it does is crashes. By the way, I am running this in an emulator.

Answer (score 2):

There several issues with your code.
   a) First of all if you decided to attach a click event to a Button from the XML code, the method being invoked should take a `View` parameter.

The signature should be like this:

```
public void WriteMsg(View view) {
}
```

b) Secondly, the name of the method should match what the value of onClick attribute.
Actually you have this in XML:

```
android:onClick="writeMsg"
```

and this is the declation of method:

```
public void WriteMsg()
```

Notice the first letter is capitalized.

c) And the last one, there's no need in setting a click listener to the `button_send` inside the `WriteMsg()` method. you already attached a click event listener by declaring the `onClick` attribute.  This may cause additional issues.

So, you either remove the `onClick` attribute, or remove the code that sets the listener for the `button_send` in the `WriteMsg` method.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
public class GraphicsActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_graphics);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_send);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello);
                tv.setText("Hello World");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class GraphicsActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_graphics);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_send);
        WriteMsg();
    }

    public void WriteMsg() {
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello);
                tv.setText("Hello World");
                setContentView(tv);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello);
```

write this in your `onCreate()` method.And use `Toast` in your `onClickListener()' of button.

```
 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Discard", 10000).show();
```

This will help you

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello);
```

try to find your text view in button and not in whole layout (as method belongs to button).
You should do like this:

```
public void WriteMsg() {

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_send);
    final TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hello);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            tv.setText("Hello World");

        }
    });

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception is at

> android:onClick="writeMsg"

but your activity has a onclick function as    `WriteMsg` . Change it to lower case `writeMsg`.
You are most probably getting method not found exception

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public TextView tv;
public Button btn_click;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    btn_click = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    btn_click.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            writeText("Text to display");
        }
    });

}

private void writeText(String string) {
    tv.setText(string);
}
```

}